# Питон вопрос про списки

Tags: python

Помогите пожалуйста понять, почему в список добавляется пустое значение '', прошлось ставить доп условие i !=''.

```
num = input()
    li = []

num = num.split(' ')

for i in num:
    if i not in li and i != '':
        li.append(i)

for j in li:
    print(j, end=" ")
```

Comment: Что вы вводите в терминале?

Comment: Возможно вы где-то разделяете значения двумя пробелами, тогда пустая строка между этими двумя пробелами становится отдельным элементом. Попробуйте просто split делать без параметров: `num = num.split()`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> input().split(' ')
1 2 3
['1', '2', '3']
>>> input().split(' ')
1 2 3 
['1', '2', '3', '']
>>>
```

второй раз я умышленно нажал пробел перед тем как нажать Enter, можно добавить вызов метода .strip()

```
>>> input().strip().split(" ")
1 2 3 
['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: а можно просто `split()` сделать и тогда не будет никаких `''`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, задача состояла в том, чтобы через пробел задать ряд чисел, я видимо случайно нажимала в начале пробел, что и давало пустое значение, тогда вопрос отпадает, все понятно)

Answer (score 0):

судя по коду вы хотите получить список уникальных слов?

почему бы тогда просто не сделать так:

```
arr = set(input().spplit())
print(*arr, sep=' ')
```